# Laravel 5 method does not exist in Controller while used PHP __callStatic method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 on PHP 5.5.9

Instead of hard coding methods in the following controller, I used PHP __callStatic method to dynamically add functionality. It works fine while I tried from Console But while calling methods route, I am getting the following error

Method App\Http\Controllers\showCategory::latest() does not exist

Here is my Route

```
Route::get('Category/{id}',               'showCategory@latest');
```

Here is my Controller

```
class showCategory extends Controller
{

public $methods = [
    'latest'        => 'created_at', 
    'newArrival'    => 'created_at', 
    'mostViewed'    => 'views'
];

public function get( $link_or_id, $orderBy = 'created_at' )
{

}

public static function __callStatic($func, $arg)
{

    $category = new self();

    if( array_key_exists( $func, $category->methods ) )
    {

        return $category->get( $arg[0], $category->methods[ $func ] );

    }

} 

}
```

Any help to point where I messed up ?

Comment: Consider if Laravel calls controller functions in object or static context

Comment: Try changing `public static function __callStatic` to `public function __call`

Comment: __call will not work as the method is being called statically.

Answer (score 0):

__callStatic() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in a static context.

showCategory::latest(); it works

and it logically how you put latest method in routes and you know if it is found or not, if you put in routes it must be found in controller

Comment: While I accessed this method from console, it worked as expected but not from route. I don't know why. That's the answer I am trying to figure out.  Thanks.